# Global activity timeline / show combined activity on all records

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, chatter, activities

I'm looking for a way to display *everything* that's been going on in my org on the home page in an activity-history kind of view.

Essentially like the facebook news feed, where you see everything happening across all records, just without any weighting (just display the most recent updates on top).

We have a small org and everyone is always on Salesforce, so it's actually not that crazy to show everyone everything.

Is there a way to do that? Ideally without code.

Comment: Are you asking if you can put a Chatter Feed component on a Lightning Home Page?

Comment: Yes, but that Chatter Feed should show _everything_ that's going on in an Org.

Answer (score 1):

Off hand, I don't know of a way to share a chatter feed with a user who's not subscribed to something without @mentioning them. You could potentially auto-subscribe all of your users to "everything" or at least to particular groups you felt were relevant you wanted to display (unless you want them to follow all records).

As I think about this, there is a library that might help with what you want to do. You can find it on GitHub. It's the [ConnectAPIHelper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper). There's much more to it than what's described in the general description.

Potentially, you could @mention a group that included everyone in your org, then publish the feed to a component you put on the home page.

Comment: Thanks, that's so weird. A global company timeline is a pretty simple requirement and makes sense for smaller firms ...